# not seeing the error message I've set on the catch method (Java)

Tags: java, try-catch

The program will ask for an integer as an input. I've set an error message in the catch method in case the input is a character or anything aside from an integer. However, I am not seeing the error message when I try to input a letter. I've also tried different Exception type and the corresponding imports, but there's no difference. Here's the code:

```
public class Random1 {

public static void main(String[] args){

    int g;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
    g = input.nextInt();


    Random r = new Random();
    int a = r.nextInt(10) + 1;

    try {
        if (g == a) {

            System.out.println("**************");
            System.out.println("*  YOU WON!  *");
            System.out.println("**************");
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");

        } else if (g != a) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, better luck next time!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Not a valid input. Error :" + e.getMessage());

    }
```

Comment: try adding a "System.out.println(g);" after g = input.nextInt(). See what you get here when you type a letter

Comment: Errors, but not the one I've written on the catch method.

Comment: Theres no possible error that could occur within your try/catch block, if you want to check the validity of the input, move your `g = input.nextInt();` line into the try/catch block. Or as mfrankli said, just put `System.out.println(g);` at the end or something to test the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that throws the exception must go in the try block